# How do I get the Windows Computer file count without listing the files?

Tags: java, windows, file, command-line, counter

Is there a way to show the file count without listing the files?

I have a Java program in which I want to list the total number of files on the hard drive of the Windows computer. The only ways that I know of list all the files before printing the total.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what kind of program?

Comment: I may expand the program in the future but currently I am making a program to report on the PC statistics (storage space, storage space available, number of files, number of directory's...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get the number of files without enumerating the whole folder tree.  Note that you don't have to visit each file, but should be able to get a file count in each folder which you then accumulate as you traverse the tree.  I believe this is the fastest way to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

That's the only way to do it. If you right-click on a large folder and do Properties, you'll see that Explorer takes some time to walk through the file system and total things up. If Microsoft can't figure out a way to speed up the process, it's unlikely you'll be able to.